# Why does install.php result in a "Page not found" error?

Tags: 7, installation

I've followed all instructions to the letter, including those in various fixes mentioned in search results for this specific issue.  I'm still getting an error.  The install script seems to work all the way through the final step, which calls for setup of the admin account.  Once I complete that form and click to continue, I get the following error message:

**The requested page "/install.php?profile=standard&locale=en" could not be found.**

Examples of fixes mentioned elsewhere include turning off opcache and changing the database collation.  I'm installing on a shared Linux platform that more than meets the system requirements.

Why does install.php result in a "Page not found" error?

Comment: Can you elaborate more? Which Drupal7 version you are trying to install. How have you uploaded Drupal code on shared hosting? Have you created Database?